# Supremum of a sequence of measures again a measure?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

can Someone help me with the following question?

Let $(\mu_n)$ be a sequence of measures on $(X, \mathcal {A})$ and define a set function $\mu: \mathcal{A} \rightarrow [0,\infty]$ by letting $\mu(A) = \sup_n \mu_n(A)$. Is $\mu$ always a measure?

Comment: You need to prove that the supremum $\mu$ has all the properties of a measure individually (i.e. non-negativity, null empty set, and countable additivity). Which property is giving you trouble?

Comment: What have you tried? To get you started, if $\nu$ is this set function, what would it take for it to satisfy $\nu(A\cup B)=\nu(A)+\nu(B)$ for disjoint $A$ and $B$? You could play with a measurable space of just two points.

Comment: Let me just note as a reference that it's indeed possible to define a "supremum of measures", using the construction pointed out here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/64164/defining-a-measure-as-a-supremum

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider, on the set $S=\{x,y\}$ the measure $\mu_1$ defined as $\mu_1(A)$ is $1$ exactly when $x\in A$ and the measure $\mu_2(A)$ defined to be $1$ whenever $y\in A$. Then, their supremum would be the function $\mu(A)$ that assigns $1$ to every non-empty set $A$. Prove that this $\mu$ is not a measure.

Comment: Well then the measure of the union would be one because the union is not empty but the countable sum would Not be equal to one and thus its no measure?

Comment: It's not very clear what you're saying there - be explicit about what sets you're taking the union of and why it contradicts additivity.

Comment: Take $A_1$ to be the set, such that $x \in A_1$ and $A_2$ be the set, such that $y \in A_2$. Then $\mu(\bigcup_i A_i) = 1$ but $\mu(A_1)+\mu(A_2)=2$, so contradiction?

Comment: That's correct; it's probably better to just write $A_1=\{x\}$ and $A_2=\{y\}$ (and it's obvious that $x\in\{x\}$), but you get the idea.